# Retrieve custom size thumbnail from video

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using [sseffa/video-api](https://github.com/sseffa/laravel-video-api) to retrieve details from Vimeo url.
There are 2 predefined thumbnail sizes 
'thumbnail_small' => $data->thumbnail_small,
'thumbnail_large' => $data->thumbnail_large,

There is another medium size (thumbnail_medium), which results in 200x150 image

How do i pull custom 480x360 size? What is api data field for it?
For example how to pull this size http://i.vimeocdn.com/video/585763747_480x360.jpg

Comment: get the image then resize it using php `imagecopyresized` function 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Comment: Thanks, I only store links to the image, I guess it easier to modify vimeo link to reflect needed size before adding it to DB

Comment: I agree this would be useful. It seems you can generate any size thumbnail by changing the dimensions in the URL. But I'm worried that if I alter the URL myself, without using the API to request a custom size, the URL may change at some point and my links will break.